# How to connect react with remote server

Tags: reactjs, backend

I am a new one for web development

I have developed front end with react js and now i need to connect to the remote server `(ex URL: https://beta-api.abc.com/auth/login)`. So my question is

1)How to connect and what are the ways to connect with the above URL and which is the best and easiest way.

2)Do i need any programming language such as Python or java or php to connect

Thank you..

Comment: Let me give a practical example based from overdub60's answer. This is a public dummy api: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/ `fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => console.log(json))`

You can even try that right in this page using dev tools (if you have chrome). (1)Right click and inspect element (2) Open up console (3) input that code above `fetch....` (4) press enter. and after a few milliseconds the output will be logged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're trying to connect to a REST API? Then you don't need another programming language, you can just use JavaScript's own features. Have a look at `fetch` and `asnyc/await`. Also, there's a nice library called `axios` that you can check out that makes some of that stuff more convenient.

Hope that helps.